# Can R packages be installed and ran on a cluster from a personal repository?

Tags: r

R is installed on our University cluster, but users do not have permission to install packages in the main repository. Is it possible to set up a personal or temporary repository in my user login where I can install and run R packages?

I have been trying to install the package using install.packages:

```
>install.packages('BiocInstaller_1.13.2.tar.gz', destdir="/home/jti222/programs",
lib="/home/jti222/R", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Then it returns the following message:

```
/share/cluster/apps/R/2.8.1/lib64/R/bin/INSTALL: line 280: /usr/bin/sed: No such 
file or directory
ERROR: cannot extract package from 'BiocInstaller_1.13.2.tar.gz'
Warning message: In install.packages("BiocInstaller_1.13.2.tar.gz", destdir =    
"/home/jti222/programs",  : installation of package 'BiocInstaller_1.13.2.tar.gz' 
had non-zero exit status
```

Is there a missing argument or is it not possible to do this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R 2.8.1 is very old (2009?); recent versions would ask, when you tried `install.packages()` or `source("http://biocondcutor.org/biocLite.R"); biocLite()`, if you'd like to install the package in your own library, i.e., exactly what you're trying to do! Also, versions of BiocInstaller are designed to work with specific versions of R, and version 1.13.* is meant to work with the current development (to become 3.1) version of R; you're not going to have any long-term happiness trying to run current Bioconductor packages on several-year-old R.

Ask your system administrator to install a recent R; no sense having a fancy cluster running old software.

Or install R yourself. It's not actually too hard (this might be an understatement, especially if the installed software is as old as the R software); here are the [official instructions](http://cran.fhcrc.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html); you'll only need to figure out sections 1 and 2.1, something along the lines of

```
mkdir ~/src && cd ~/src
svn checkout https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/ R-devel
R-devel/tools/rsync-recommended
mkdir ~/bin/R-devel && cd ~/bin/R-devel
~/src/R-devel/configure && make -j
```

followed by

```
~/bin/R-devel/bin/R
```

might get you most of the way there. If there are significant problems, e.g., about missing libxml or other missing / outdated libraries, then your best bet is to talk with your system administrator.